# Javascript button to open a modal; button doesn't work when in a list

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I want to press a button (matched to a person) that brings up a pop-up (right now using a modal) of an  of another page which will vary based on which person it is. I am using a basic template from the w3school and I can get one button working, but when I try and add a button into the list to match a person, the modal does not open. Obviously for each button to be assigned to one person they will need to have their own element id, but why cant I get even one button to work?
Its the "show on map" button in the snippet below.
The top most "show on map" button works in the sense that it brings up the modal, but the same buttons in the list do nothing.

Thank you in advance.

```js
 // Get the modal
 var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

 // Get the button that opens the modal
 var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

 // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
 btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";
 }

 // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
 span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
 }

 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
     modal.style.display = "none";
   }
 }
```

```css
/*DESKTOP*/

/* The Modal (background) */

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  .modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
  }
  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: clear;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0% auto 15% auto;
    /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #ffc948;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #640006;
    color: white;
    height: 2em;
  }
  .modal-body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* Add Animation */
  @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      bottom: -300px;
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      bottom: -300px;
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
/*MOBILE*/

/* The Modal (background) */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
  }
  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: clear;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0% auto 15% auto;
    /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #ffc948;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #640006;
    color: white;
    height: 2em;
  }
  .modal-body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* Add Animation */
  @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      bottom: -300px;
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      bottom: -300px;
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #810008;
}
a.menu-link {
  color: #ffc948;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.menu-link span {
  border-bottom: solid 3px #000;
  border-top: double 10px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 5px -3px 0;
  width: 30px;
}
.menu-link:hover span {
  border-color: #666;
}
.menu,
.menu > ul,
.menu > ul ul {
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 0;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-left: 15%;
}
.menu.active {
  background: #640006;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #64006;
  border-top: 1px solid #64006;
  margin: 1em 0 1em -12px;
  max-height: 55em;
  width: 100vw;
}
.js .menu > ul ul.active {
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 55em;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > ul {
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.menu li a {
  color: #ffc948;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.04em;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span.has-subnav {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  top: 0;
}
/*NAV MENU CSS MOBILE */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .menu,
  .menu > ul ul {
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .menu li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc948;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .menu li li a {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  .menu li:last-child a {
    border: none;
  }
  .menu li li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc948;
  }
  .menu li:hover {
    background: #640006;
  }
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background: #ffc948;
  color: black;
}
/*NAV MENU CSS DESKTOP*/

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc948;
  }
  a.menu-link {
    display: none;
  }
  .js .menu,
  .js .menu > ul ul {
    max-height: none;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .js .menu > ul li:hover > ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    height: 44px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu span.has-subnav {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu li a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .menu li li a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #fff;
  }
  .menu ul ul {
    background: #640006;
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 5px 5px;
    border-top: solid 2px transparent;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 43px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .chrome .js .menu > ul ul {
    top: 43px;
  }
  .menu ul ul.wide {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .menu ul ul li {
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu > ul ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .menu ul ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffc948;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.list {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.alphalist {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  top: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.list li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc948;
  line-height: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}
.list .divider {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: -60px 0 0 #fafafa;
  line-height: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 44px;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffc948;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
h2 {
  color: #ffc948;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
h3 {
  line-height: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  color: #ffc948;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
#scrolling {
  padding-top: 44px;
  padding-right: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .list .divider {
    top: 0;
  }
}
.modal-button {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 4px 2%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 4px 2%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Show on Map</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times</span>
      <h2>Career Fair Map</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <iframe src="map.html" width="500px" height="700px">
      </iframe>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="scrolling">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="divider" id="a">A</li>
    <li><a href="#">Amelia Webster</a>
      <button class="button" onclick="alert('## has been added to favorites.')">Favorite</button>
      <button class="button" id="myBtn">Show on Map</button>
      <li><a href="#">Andrew WifKinson</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Archibald Carrington</a>
        <button class="modal-button" id="myBtn">Show on Map</button>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ariana Clapton</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ashley Carter</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" id="b">B</li>
      <li><a href="#">Barney Mercer</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Barry Goodman</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Brenda Brown</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Brooke Creighton</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" id="c">C</li>
      <li><a href="#">Camilla Kapinksy</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Caroline Miller</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Charlotte Gardner</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Cynthia Monroe</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" id="e">E</li>
      <li><a href="#">Elizabeth Abramson</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Elizabeth Cook</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ernie Carter</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Evelyn Nash</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" id="f">F</li>
      <li><a href="#">Fyodor Dostoevsky</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id's should always be unique.

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be
>   unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element
>   when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
>   (with CSS).

That is also the origin of your problem. `document.getElementById("theid");` will return the first element (and also the only element expected to use this id). However you want to assign your onclick method to multiple buttons.

You should consider to use the `name` attribute instead. Then you can use `document.getElementsByName("myBtn")` in order to loop through all buttons and register your listener. The code below contains comments that should explain my changes.

```js
 // Get the modal
 var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

 // Get all buttons that should opens the modal
 var btns = document.getElementsByName("myBtn");

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
 
 // The iframe inside of the Modal
 var modalIFrame = document.getElementById("modal-iframe");

 // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
 for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
   (function(i) {
     var btn = btns[i];
     // you should use addEventListener("click", function() {}); here
     btn.onclick = function() {
       // this will set the iframe url every time you press a button and add the "id" of the button that was pressed as a parameter. "id" is just the current index of the for loop for now.
       modalIFrame.setAttribute("src", "map.html?id=" + i);
       modal.style.display = "block";
     }
   })(i);
 }

 // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
 span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
 }

 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
     modal.style.display = "none";
   }
 }
```

```css
/*DESKTOP*/

/* The Modal (background) */

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  .modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
  }
  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: clear;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0% auto 15% auto;
    /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #ffc948;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #640006;
    color: white;
    height: 2em;
  }
  .modal-body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* Add Animation */
  @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      bottom: -300px;
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      bottom: -300px;
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
/*MOBILE*/

/* The Modal (background) */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
  }
  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: clear;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0% auto 15% auto;
    /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #ffc948;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #640006;
    color: white;
    height: 2em;
  }
  .modal-body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* Add Animation */
  @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      bottom: -300px;
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      bottom: -300px;
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #810008;
}
a.menu-link {
  color: #ffc948;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.menu-link span {
  border-bottom: solid 3px #000;
  border-top: double 10px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 5px -3px 0;
  width: 30px;
}
.menu-link:hover span {
  border-color: #666;
}
.menu,
.menu > ul,
.menu > ul ul {
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 0;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-left: 15%;
}
.menu.active {
  background: #640006;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #64006;
  border-top: 1px solid #64006;
  margin: 1em 0 1em -12px;
  max-height: 55em;
  width: 100vw;
}
.js .menu > ul ul.active {
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 55em;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > ul {
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.menu li a {
  color: #ffc948;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.04em;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span.has-subnav {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  top: 0;
}
/*NAV MENU CSS MOBILE */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .menu,
  .menu > ul ul {
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .menu li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc948;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .menu li li a {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  .menu li:last-child a {
    border: none;
  }
  .menu li li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc948;
  }
  .menu li:hover {
    background: #640006;
  }
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background: #ffc948;
  color: black;
}
/*NAV MENU CSS DESKTOP*/

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc948;
  }
  a.menu-link {
    display: none;
  }
  .js .menu,
  .js .menu > ul ul {
    max-height: none;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .js .menu > ul li:hover > ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    height: 44px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu span.has-subnav {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu li a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .menu li li a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #fff;
  }
  .menu ul ul {
    background: #640006;
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 5px 5px;
    border-top: solid 2px transparent;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 43px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .chrome .js .menu > ul ul {
    top: 43px;
  }
  .menu ul ul.wide {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .menu ul ul li {
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu > ul ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .menu ul ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffc948;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.list {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.alphalist {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  top: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.list li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc948;
  line-height: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}
.list .divider {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: -60px 0 0 #fafafa;
  line-height: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 44px;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffc948;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
h2 {
  color: #ffc948;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
h3 {
  line-height: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  color: #ffc948;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
#scrolling {
  padding-top: 44px;
  padding-right: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .list .divider {
    top: 0;
  }
}
.modal-button {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 4px 2%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 4px 2%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Changed id="myBtn" to name="myBtn" -->
<button name="myBtn">Show on Map</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times</span>
      <h2>Career Fair Map</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <iframe id="modal-iframe" src="map.html" width="500px" height="700px">
      </iframe>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="scrolling">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="divider" id="a">A</li>
    <li><a href="#">Amelia Webster</a>
      <button class="button" onclick="alert('## has been added to favorites.')">Favorite</button>
      <!-- Changed id="myBtn" to name="myBtn" -->
      <button class="button" name="myBtn">Show on Map</button>
      <li><a href="#">Andrew WifKinson</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Archibald Carrington</a>
        <!-- Changed id="myBtn" to name="myBtn" -->
        <button class="modal-button" name="myBtn">Show on Map</button>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ariana Clapton</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ashley Carter</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" id="b">B</li>
      <li><a href="#">Barney Mercer</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Barry Goodman</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Brenda Brown</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Brooke Creighton</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" id="c">C</li>
      <li><a href="#">Camilla Kapinksy</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Caroline Miller</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Charlotte Gardner</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Cynthia Monroe</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" id="e">E</li>
      <li><a href="#">Elizabeth Abramson</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Elizabeth Cook</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ernie Carter</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Evelyn Nash</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider" id="f">F</li>
      <li><a href="#">Fyodor Dostoevsky</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: fantastic...so what was the var btn, is now btns, which is an array of all buttons with the name myBtn?

Comment: that is correct. you can use the btn variable to do anything for every button that is named "myBtn"

Comment: Thank you so much! So hypothetically if I wanted the modal to show something different for each button, would I just reference it as btn[i]?
Ideally, each show map button will highlight a table on a map, the map being another .html doc and with tables being added using arrays, which I'm in the process of making, but would I be able to use btn[i] to reference a given button?

Comment: For example if you want the first button to not open a modal but instead alert "Hello" you could check if the variable `i` is (in this case) 0 and dont display the modal when clicked but `alert("Hello")`. However if you want to show different data based on the button that was pressed i would suggest you to store that data in an array or even fetch it from the server when needed and read it using the index or a key that was specified using a data attribute.

Comment: So right now I have it set up to click the button, which will open a modal with an <iframe> in it of another .html doc (map.html). Map.html is basically an image with rectangles made over it in css. My thought was that I could write some javascript within map.html to change which table is highlighted based on which button (on this main page) is pressed. Is that possible or is there not a way for maps.html to know which btn[i] is pressed?

Comment: this is possible by adding a parameter to the iframes url like so: map.html?id=0. you can use any name for that parameter and fetch it using a javascript inside the map.html file. you can also use a server side language to generate map.html based on the parameter passed so that it does need no javascript in oder to highlight the desired area. i will update my answer to provide an example.

Comment: if you want to use the approach that needs javascript inside map.html you will need to fetch the parameter from the url. There are serveral ways to do that. You can use this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript . However there are serveral ways to do what you want to do. So at the end you have to decide which one will fit your needs the best.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to look into that and see if I can figure that out. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: no problem, if you have any further question, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML the `id` attribute is unique. As such, you are only ever binding to the first button with the id of `myBtn` (I go and get the element by id and I only get one because that's what's expected).

You will need to make the IDs unique and bind each one's click event, that or apply a class, get an array of buttons by class, and bind each button in the array.

If you had a class named `showModalButton` set on each button you could get the references with:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('showModalButton');
```

and then iterate over the elements and bind:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
       }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense in my head, but even without that first button there, the next button (first in the lists) becomes the first button but still won't work.
I understand that each button will need to have its own ID, and I'll probably do that with an array somehow, but even if the first button is removed, the next one should work, but doesn't.